# common way to use images and text in html5 apps

Tags: html, image

i want to build a HTML5 App via Phonegap like a mobile site. I want to know what´s the best way to embed buttons with text in the app. The problem is, that it is responsive, so it is very difficult to put images as background and use html text. On the other hand the images may get diffused if the screen of the device gets to big. Another point would be the data amount the several images need.

What is the common way to use buttons with text in HTML5 Apps?

thanks :)

Comment: Why dont you use `background-size` css property? HTML would be the best way with Phonegap, otherwise you could build a native Java app.

Comment: Didn´t figure out how to use it properly so it will work.. If it is the most reasonable way i would try it, but in case i am trying things which don´t make sense i´d like to know first. that´s the point of my question

Comment: You could use html canvas to add overlays to your image, after it was taken, and then preview it.